# Get Toolbars to Ubuntu (like in Windows) and make icons smaller

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Is there any way for toolbars in ubuntu, there is a picture of my current windows taskbar, that's the biggest thing of windows what is keeping me on there. (normally the taskbar is at my right.)[image: My windows Toolbar]

Comment: Uh... where's the Start button?

Comment: @MarkYisri Ctrl+Esc or windows key, it wastes space for me, since I shut the machine down from WIN+X Menu Anyways and have 1 keyboard macro key for it as well. It is hidden by StartKiller.

Answer (score 2):

Look into Ubuntu system settings > Desktop,from there you can resize icons as you want.I made it a long time ago but I think to remember well

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04 you just go to ***System Settings*** > ***Appearance***.  Move the slider to set the ***Launcher icon size*** to whatever value you find comfortable.